# Clear only the rectangles in the html5 canvas (my code clear everything)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Here my jsfiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/2/

When i click on Clear IT button, i want to remove only the rectangles in the canvas, image must still there ... and my second problem is that when it clear everything, after that i can't make again a rectangles into the canvas.

And here the code that erase everything:

```
function clearIt() {
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
}
```

**Note:** Click and drag your mouse on the image in order to create rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
function clearIt() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
}
```

with:

```
function clearIt() {
    shapes = [];
    draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `shapes` to be an empty array after you press the button.

```
function clearIt() {
  shapes = []
}
```

Updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/3/